# Python Comparing Datetimes with NaT in Columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a date frame like that has a submit and resolved date

```
  Incident ID   Submit_Date  Resolved_Date 
   INC001.       2021-02-25  2021-03-02     
   INC002        2021-02-27  2021-03-01    
   INC003        2021-02-27  NaT          
   INC004        2021-04-01  NaT
```

I have a function to count the tickets if they meet a certain criteria but with the NaT's it won't read them with the comparison

part of the function I am having problems is like this
The function it is looking if the rows resolved date is empty and the other tickets resolved date is empty then summing it for a count in a new column

```
 result = list()
  for row in df.iterrows():
     cur_data = row[1]
     result.append(((cur_data['Resolved_Date'] is pd.NaT) & (df['Resolved_Date'] is pd.NaT))).sum())

 df['Count'] = result
```

I want the result to look like this

```
  Incident ID Submit_Date  Resolved_Date  Count
   INC001        2021-02-25  2021-03-02     0
   INC002        2021-02-27  2021-03-01     0
   INC003        2021-02-27  NaT            2 # counting itself and the other NA resolved date
   INC004        2021-04-01  NaT            2 # counting itself and the other NA resolved date
```

Right now it is ignoring the NaTs

Comment: What is count derived from? What makes the two rows with `NaT` have a count of 2?

Comment: The count is derived from the result. append function, I edited the result for the counts

Comment: Yes but what is the logic behind the two rows with a type of `pd.NaT` having a count of 2? When you say count of tickets, in your example we do not have any tickets?

Comment: Should every row with a `pd.NaT` have a count of the total `pd.NaT` over every row in the df?

Comment: It is counting the rows that meet the functions criteria, in this case the two first tickets both had a resolve date, it didn't meet the criteria so it wasn't counted @PacketLoss

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get total count of `NaT` in  `Resolved_Date` column and put it in a new column against `NaT` values of `Resolved_Date` then this should work.

**Code**

```
NaT_check = df['Resolved_Date'].isna()
df['Count'] = np.where(NaT_check, NaT_check.sum(),0)
df
```

**Output**

```
    Incident ID Submit_Date Resolved_Date   Count
0   INC001  2021-02-25  2021-03-02          0
1   INC002  2021-02-27  2021-03-01          0
2   INC003  2021-02-27  NaT                 2
3   INC004  2021-04-01  NaT                 2
```

Comment: So are you saying for the entire df you are counting the number of rows with resolved_date = 0 and the number of rows with no resolved_date = 2? 

If that's the case the table structure doesn't really make sense. But yes, this code should work for the output you expect

Comment: Just a minor correction, we are not touching entire df but the required column.

Comment: I have other comparisons in my function but I listed the one that is giving me trouble, so I still need it to be in the comparison format I think

Comment: @Uts the result.append function has more in comparing normal date times but I also need it to compare Null datetimes